# Change the color of toolbar item icon

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a toolbar in its menu place i have placed  a default icon

[image: deafult icon]

placed there 
and when the user clicks it i want to change the color and fill it with to black heart

[image: change icon]

I have tried below method but didn't worked

This is my java code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    this.menu = menu;
    if (menu != null) {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.favouriteProperty);
        if (item != null) {
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
        }
    }

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is 
present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scrolling, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This is my xml code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.myapplication.ScrollingActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/favouriteProperty"
android:title="Edit Profile"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_heart"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/shareProperty"
    android:title="Edit Profile"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: you can change the heart image click on the button

Answer (score 1):

`onCreateOptionsMenu` is used to initially create the menu. You need to change the icon in `onOptionsItemSelected`. Something along the following lines should work,

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.favouriteProperty:
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

P.S - Since you're using this for favoriting, you'll probably also want to save the user's choice, and use their choice to determine the icon to use in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.